# Customizing webform results submission page

Tags: 7, views, webforms

I'm new to drupal. I'm using the Drupal 7 version. I have created one webform with Name, gender, program, branch, district, college..etc fields. And now I want to customize the webform result submissions page. I want to display the submission list based on the district selected. Can anyone help me with this? I will be very thankful.

Answer (score 1):

Look at [EntityForms](https://drupal.org/project/entityform) to have more control over submissions and selecting what submissions to view.

```
Features
Ability to attach any Drupal Field to the Forms
Ability to use most field based and entity aware modules.
You can download submitted data to XML and / or CSV data files using View Data Export.
Rules based form submission notifications. Allows for complex notifications logic.
Rules based form access control. Allows for complex access logic.
Use Views to create to create an administrative listing of each Entityform type Submissions for fine grain control.
```

Comment: awesome module I came across it last week

Answer (score 0):

I believe we have fewer options left while displaying webform submission results
but we can always do it with node form and can easily enjoy cck fields flexibility. You can create a content type with the same set of fields s on webform and can allow permissions to create node of that content type for user roles as per your requirement, the simply create a view of that content type and you will have all options over there to filter, group your results to any field you want.

Comment: here is the way to create content type
go to structure->content type->add content type
give name to your content type
click on save and add field
does that make sense?
then on the next form add cck fields, remember you can not unset the title field over there but can rename it to first name etc.

Comment: If you want to do this then use https://drupal.org/project/entityform